# Simple fields for performance on table with 230 rows

Tags: simple-form

We are trying to embed two simple form fields as columns in a table, we noticed that it takes about 4.5 seconds for simple fields to generate those tags. The table has 230 rows.

Performance with the simple_fields_for block commented out is .5 seconds, with simple fields for : 5 seconds

```
= simple_form_for :account,url: create_transactions_path, method: :put do |f|
  %table.table.table-striped
  ......
  ........
  ........
    %tbody
      - loans_view = loans_view(@loans)
      - loans_view.each do |lv|
        - loan = lv[:loan]
        - account = loan.account
      .......
      .......
      %td
        = lv[:amount_due]
      = f.simple_fields_for :loan, index: loan.id do |al_f|
        = al_f.simple_fields_for :account_transaction, index: account.id do |act_f|
          %td
            = act_f.input :amount, label: false, input_html:{value: account.top_up_amount}
          %td
            = act_f.input :include_for_update, as: :boolean, label: false, input_html: {checked: true}
```

We had enabled logging and made sure no db call goes out or any time consuming API is being called in the simple fields for block.